# Save scan from excel as jpeg image

Tags: excel, vba

I need to digitize documents from excel. With the following macro, I manage to open a dialog box at the end of the scan but but with the extension xlsm, I would need to save the jpeg images that I scanned by choosing file name and folder with jpeg extension.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim FinestraDiDialogo  As Object
Dim Immagine As Object
Set scansione = CreateObject("WIA.CommonDialog")
Set Immagine = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
Do
Set Immagine = scansione.ShowAcquireImage(ScannerDeviceType, 
ColorIntent, MaximizeQuality)
Call getSaveAsFilenameFromUser(, "JPG")
Loop Until MsgBox("Vuoieseguire una nuova scansione? ", vbYesNo + 
vbQuestion, "Scansione documento ") = vbNo
End Sub
Public Function getSaveAsFilenameFromUser(Optional initialFileOrPath As 
String, Optional fileExtension As String) As String

Dim fileFilter As String
'e.g. jpeg (*.jpeg), "*.jpeg"   for fileExtension jpeg
fileFilter = fileExtension & " (*." & fileExtension & "), ""*." & 
fileExtension & """"

Dim varResult As Variant
varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(initialFileOrPath, fileFilter)

If varResult <> False And LenB(varResult) > 0 Then
getSaveAsFilenameFromUser = varResult
End If

End Function`
```

Answer (score 0):

`Application.GetSaveAsFilename` is your friend - as you can pass the extension to it

For these occasions I am using a generic function to which you can pass the default path/filename and the extension. It returns either the full filename or an empty string - if the user cancels the dialog

```vb
Public Function getSaveAsFilenameFromUser(Optional initialFileOrPath As String, Optional fileExtension As String) As String

Dim fileFilter As String
'e.g. jpeg (*.jpeg), "*.jpeg"   for fileExtension jpeg
fileFilter = fileExtension & " (*." & fileExtension & "), ""*." & fileExtension & """"
 
Dim varResult As Variant

varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(initialFileOrPath, fileFilter)
 
If varResult <> False And LenB(varResult) > 0 Then
    getSaveAsFilenameFromUser = varResult
End If

End Function
```

As I prefer to not have business logic in on-click events I would create a general `scanSaveImage`-routine in a normal module which then calls the `getSaveAsFilenameFromUser`-function.

Furthermore I would set some default constants for the scan variables.

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-icommondialog-showacquireimage I would suppose that you can use the following default values

```vb
Option Explicit

'adjust these values to your needs

Private Const defaultPath As String = "D:\ScannedImages\"

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-wiadevicetype
Private Const defaultScannerDeviceType As long = 1   'ScannerDeviceType

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-wiaimageintent
Private Const defaultColorIntent As long = 0  'UnspecifiedIntent  

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-wiaimagebias
Private Const defaultQuality As long = 131072   'MaximizeQuality


Public Sub scanSaveImage(Optional ScannerDeviceType As long = defaultScannerDeviceType, _
    Optional ColorIntent As long = defaultColorIntent, _
    Optional Quality As long = defaultQuality)

Dim scansione As Object, Immagine As Object
Set scansione = CreateObject("WIA.CommonDialog")

Dim fullFilename As String

Do
    Set Immagine = scansione.ShowAcquireImage(ScannerDeviceType, ColorIntent, Quality)
    
    fullFilename = getSaveAsFilenameFromUser(defaultPath, "jpeg")
    If fullFilename <> vbNullString Then
        Immagine.SaveAs fullFilename
    End If
    
Loop Until MsgBox("Procedo ad una nuova scansione? ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Scansione documento ") = vbNo

End Sub
```

Your `onclick`-Routine would look like this

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
scanSaveImage
End Sub
```

Side-advantage: whenever someone gets to the onClick-event - he or she will understand immediately what happens here - without reading multiple code lines.
Btw: if you rename the button to e.g. cmdScanSaveImage it enhances the readability of the code as well

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I'm trying to set the parameters of the variables where you put XXX but I can't figure out how to set them, can you give me an example? I currently use a Xerox Versalink B405 networked scanner and would need to set a scan at 300 dpi.

Comment: I thought you already defined them as you are using them in your routine already: `Set Immagine = scansione.ShowAcquireImage(ScannerDeviceType, ColorIntent, MaximizeQuality). I updated the code with the default values based on this URL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-icommondialog-showacquireimage. But I have no scanner to test the code.